# Angular 2 project (in Visual Studio 2015) -- anchor tags < a > in the .html page not rendering

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-2015

I have been working on an Angular 2 sample project from Visual Studio 2015.  I have the Update 3 for VS2015, TypeScript is loaded, NPM engine is running, ... I have been developing this project, but unlike the tutorial (videos) I have not been clearing out the former tasks.  I have just been adding each task to the project.  Now I am at a part which is using anchor tags < a > < / a > in an html table, but the tags are not rendering.  The data is rendering correctly (from a simple web service connected to a sql server DB).  Below here is an image of the actual web content and what the google debugger is showing in the Elements section and below that is the html markup with the Angular 2 code.  I have had to do a few minor tweaks to my project to get it to run thus far, but now I am stuck on this anchor tag thing.  Any suggestions appreciated what I could try to resolve this.

[image]

```
<employee-count *ngIf="employees" [all]="getTotalEmployeesCount()"
            [male]="getTotalMaleEmployeesCount()"
            [female]="getTotalFemaleEmployeesCount()"
            (countRadioButtonSelectionChanged)="onEmployeeCountRadioButtonChange($event)">
</employee-count>

<br /><br />
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Annual Salary</th>
            <th>Date Of Birth</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngIf="!employees || (employees.Length < 1)">
            <td colspan="5">No Employees to display</td>
        </tr>

        <ng-container *ngFor="let employee of employees;">
            <tr *ngIf="selectedEmployeeCountRadioButton=='All' || selectedEmployeeCountRadioButton==employee.gender">
                <td>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/employees',employee.code]">  <<<----- the anchor tags not rendering
                    {{ employee.code | uppercase }}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ employee.name | employeeTitle:employee.gender }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
                <td>{{ employee.annualSalary | currency:'USD':true:'1.3-3'}}    </td>
                <td>{{ employee.dateOfBirth | date:'dd/MM/y' | uppercase }}    </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>

        <tr *ngIf="!employees">
            <td colspan="5">{{statusMessage}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button (click)="getEmployees()">Refresh Employees</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `routerLink` with a simple `href` to eliminate the possibility that interpolation is failing? I'd guess that the anchors would still render, but....

Comment: I just tried the href -- yes now the links are rendering -- however ......  it takes me to the "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" page.  the [routerLink] is supposed to render the row of the selected link.  Any ideas for a workaround for this?

Comment: Not really. You'll need to start with very simple routerLink values and find out what's actually breaking them. Be sure to update your question appropriately.

Comment: this angular 2 code l-- [routerLink]="['/employees',employee.code]">  basically is submitting the employee.code field (which is a primary key) to the application as a parameter to retrieve the selected row.  There must be some tweak maybe I missed it for making the anchor tag work here.

Comment: I removed the [] brackets from routerLink and now the links render using just routerLink without the brackets, but still going to the Page Not Found page instead of rendering the selected row.  Almost there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting some [] brackets around routerLink in the parent component

```
<div style="padding:5px">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">                        
         <li routerLinkActive="active"> <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a> </li>
         <li routerLinkActive="active"> <a [routerLink]="['employees']">Employees</a> </li>
          <br />
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Mystereiously, someone else had posted the suggestion here, but it seems to have disappeared from this thread.  I wanted to mark that as the answer.  ??  where did that post go?

The poster of the answer was Isherwood.  Many thanks.  Where did your post go?